# Python AttributeError/ImportError when importing from same folder

Tags: python, importerror, attributeerror

My code:

```
from fin.py import *
from setup.py import *
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1519, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\Documents\Programming\snake.py", line 4, in <module>
    from fin.py import *
ImportError: No module named 'fin.py'; fin is not a package
```

I am importing .py files from the same folder. Everything should work but this shows up!

EDIT: Solved! (Remove .py from the ending, I had tried this before but got a NameError due to a typo in my code. So yeah! Great!)

Answer (score 2):

When you import you can omit the .py on the end of the files.  What you're looking for is:

```
from fin import *
from setup import *
```

Comment: Is setup.py within the same folder?  It seems to be import fin.py fine - as it's passing on to the import of setup.  I just tried with simple print statements and got it to work on my machine.  Could you provide a little more detail on the error?  (Like if it's invoked by your snake.py file)

Comment: Being stupid - solved! Thanks. Always copy the ENTIRE error. I had just mistyped a function with the same name

Comment: Awesome!  Happy programming! :)